# Override style for "Collapse" of antd react component library

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am using JSX syntax with *.css for my react component. Below is the [antd collapse](https://ant.design/components/collapse/) jsx code.

```
    <Collapse
      defaultActiveKey={["1"]}
      expandIconPosition="right"
    >
      <Panel
        header="This is panel header with arrow icon"
        key="1"
      >
        <div>
          Body-123
        </div>
      </Panel>

    </Collapse>
```

Now, I would like to only style(`border: "3px solid red"`) the header part of the Collapse, which I could do using below css

```
.ant-collapse > .ant-collapse-item > .ant-collapse-header
```

But the issue is, I would like to do it dynamically depending on some condition in the jsx code. That is I have a few of such panels and each should have different border color depending on some data.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue where I wanted to conditionally style the background color of the header in each Panel component but not the content. I elected to use a css variable to provide a rule for the background color in my style sheet.

You can add a css variable with the value you derive in JavaScript through the style object:

```
style={{ ["--header-border"]: category.border }}
```

In your css file you can then consume this value in as a rule in your selector:

```
.collapse-panel-custom > .ant-collapse-header {
  border: var(--header-border, 1px solid black);
}
```

Here is a codepen of this method applied to the border of the panel header:

https://codepen.io/faltherr/pen/ZEBzeJe

Answer (score 1):

You can use `className` to dynamically set the class based on your condition and use the class name to set the border.

Here is an example which toggles border based on button click:

**Component**

```
const App = () => {
  const [hasBorder, setBorder] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button onClick={() => setBorder(!hasBorder)}>Set Border</Button>
      <Collapse
        className={hasBorder ? "" : "active"}
        defaultActiveKey={["1"]}
        expandIconPosition="right"
      >
        <Panel header="This is panel header with arrow icon" key="1">
          <div>Body-123</div>
        </Panel>
      </Collapse>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

**Style**

```
.active.ant-collapse > .ant-collapse-item > .ant-collapse-header {
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}
```

Check the demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-grothendieck-submf

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Yash, this would work for a single "Collapse. I have a "Collapse" with few "Panel" and I would like to change the color with condition. I need some way to apply to "Panel" as I loop through my data to make multiple "Panel" inside 1 "Collapse" and would like to change left-border color depending on data. TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can set inline style conditionally, check code below...

```
const hasBorder = true;
<React.Fragment>
  <Collapse
    style={hasBorder ? {border: '3px solid black'} : {}}
    defaultActiveKey={["1"]}
    expandIconPosition="right"
  >
    <Panel header="This is panel header with arrow icon" key="1">
      <div>Body-123</div>
    </Panel>
  </Collapse>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Thanks,I would like to apply "borderLeft" This way it applies to the full "Collapse", I want to have only to the header(not content area). If I apply the same to the Panel, the left border color of the full (Panel along with content area) changes. TIA